# Python Modules in Apache Nifi

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, etl, apache-nifi, minify

I'm running python script present in .py file using ExecuteStreamCommand processor in Nifi. For reading a csv file pandas modules is required. I'm calling pandas in the program but I'm getting error mentioned as "No modules Pandas found"

I have Python installed in my local and added to path to Command path.

How to install Pandas library?

Comment: `pip install pandas` on server where nifi is running...

Comment: Please check the environment in which you have installed the pandas package and the env which you are using from NiFi are the same. Best is to use base(root) env

Answer (score 0):

I’ve had a similar issue with other modules. What you need to do is install the Python modules on the NiFi server that your script calls. What the error message is telling you is that it’s trying to find the module called pandas but it isn’t installed on the host.